# Identify part for a build aggg stuck

Tags: part-identification

The part is shown in the picture.  Fingers crossed.[image]

Answer (score 4):

That's [part 2436 "Bracket 1x2 - 1x4"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2436).

[image: part 2436]

Comment: Thank you!  cheers!

Comment: @Copmedic Please see the following article: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).